# finding the probability distribution function for a linear transformation

Tags: probability

given the random variable $X \sim U[-2,3]$
find the probability distribution function
$$Z=\begin{cases}
X,  & \text{$-1\le X \le2$} \\
0, & \text{else}  \\
\end{cases}$$

I'm having difficulty in determine the border lines.
I wanted to take $t<-1, -1<t<2$ and $t>2$
and I don't understand why I need to split to another area in $t=0$

Comment: There are many reasons that $Z=0$. F.e. $Z=0$ when $X<-1$ or when $X>2$ and so on. That is not the case with the other values of $t$ in $[-1, 2]$.

Comment: I don't think you undertood me. the answer is $$ F_z(t) =
\begin{cases}
0,  & \text{$t<0$} \\
{t+1 \over 5}, & \text{%-1\ne t < 0%}  \\{t+3\over 5}, & \text{%0\ne t < 2%}  \\1, & \text{%t\ge 2%}  \\
\end{cases}$$

Comment: I understood you. See my answer below. To avoid confusing say that $Z=X for X \in [-1, 2]$ and $Z=23$ (for example) instead of $Z=0$ elsewhere. Do you see know that the value $23$ has to treated separately? That is why zero in your case has to be treated separately!

Comment: Find the probability $P(Z=0)$ and you will see it. In zero there is a disconituity! There is concentrated more probability than in other point in [-1,2]. Do you understand what I mean, or should I explain it differently

Comment: I think so. you're saying, that beacuse Z=0 within [-2,3] I need to treat it differently then zeros outside [-2,3]?

Comment: No you have to treat all the zeros the same and sum up their probability. Just think what is the probability  of $P(Z \le 0)$. You can write it as $P(Z < 0)+P(Z=0)$. But $P(Z=0)$ is alone equal to $3/5$. That is not the case for any of the other values in $[-1,2]$.  I meant before that is confusing because $0$ lies whithin $[-1,2]$. If $Z$ was defined as $Z=23$ else (instead of zero) then you it would not have confused you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there are many reasons that $Z=0$. So, $Z$ has a distribution that is a mixture of a continuous and discrete r.v. The random variable $Z$ can be written as $$Z=I_{\left\{-1\le X \le 2\right\}}X$$ So $Z$ can take values with positive probability in the interval $\left[-1,2\right].$The probability distribution function (pdf) $f_Z$ of $Z$ can be determined as the derivative of the cumulative distribution function (cdf) $F_Z$ of $Z$. The cdf of $Z$ can be written as follows $$F_Z(t)=P(Z \le t)=P(I_{\left\{-1\le X \le 2\right\}}X\le t)$$

So, in order to determine firstly the cdf of $Z$ we take cases:

1st Case: $t<-1$. $F_Z(t)=P(Z \le t)=0$

2nd Case: $-1 \le t < 0$. $$\begin{align*}F_Z(t)&=P(Z \le t)=P(-1\le X\le t)=F_X(t)-F_X(-1)=\\&=\frac{t+2}{3-(-2)}-\frac{-1+2}{3-(-2)}=\\&=\frac{t+1}{5}\end{align*}$$

3rd Case: $t=0$. $$\begin{align*}F_Z(t)&=P(Z \le 0)=P(Z < 0)+P(Z=0)=\\&=P(-1\le X\le0)+P(-2 \le X \le -1)+P(2\le X \le 3)=\\&=\frac{3}{5}\end{align*}$$

4th Case: $0<t \le 2$. $$\begin{align*}F_Z(t)&=P(Z \le t)=P(Z \le 0)+P(0<Z\le t)=\frac{3}{5}+P(0<X\le t)=\\&=\frac{3}{5}+F_X(t)-F_X(0)=\frac{3}{5}+\frac{t+2}{5}-\frac{2}{5}=\\&=\frac{t+3}{5}\end{align*}$$

5th Case: $2<t$. $F_Z(t)=0$. So in sum
$$F_Z(t)=\left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
      0 & t< -1 \\
      \frac{t+1}{5} & -1 \le t < 0 \\
      \frac{3}{5} & t=0 \\
\frac{t+3}{5} & 0 \le t < 2 \\      
1 &  2 \le t \\
\end{array} 
\right.$$
(where of course the formula $\frac{t+3}{5}$ that applies for $0<t<2$ is also true for $t=0$ so you can merge cases 3 and 4.

Comment: I don't think I understand how you calculated Z(t=0)

Comment: You have that $P(Z \le 0)=P(Z<0)+P(Z=0)$. Ok until here, or not? Then you have that $P(Z<0)=P(-1<X<0)$ and $P(Z=0)= P(-2<X<-1)+P(2<X<3)$. Now is it clear?

Comment: it was ok on the previews comment, thanks...

Comment: Ok, nice. See you!